# Get Instance from classname

Tags: android, class, instance

I'm trying to reach the current activity. The code below is from some other example and after editing has the correct name of current activity. But how do I get the actual instance from there?

```
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

     // get the info from the currently running task
     List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 

     ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;

         // this is the class-name
     componentInfo.getClassName();
```

Thanx,
Marcus

Comment: Can you clarify: The class you are running this code from is of type Context, and quite likely already an Activity (which derives from Context). Why isn't "this" the instance of the current activity already?

Comment: actually, I'd like myApplication (that extends Application) to return a reference to the current activity, so I could use it in helper-classes instead of activities only.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea; Activities are ephemeral and you should not expect them to stick around from one statement to the next unless you are actually running in their context. I suspect you need to factor out the methods/data you are accessing into a different class who's lifetime you have more control over, possibly a Service or (more controversially) a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to store the instance of the Activity in myApplication. You can then update the currently active Activity everytime an Activity reaches onResume().
But as Rupert Rawnsley said, it would be better to put your methods elsewhere (Service, Singleton, Application).

Also if you plan to use the Activity in helperclasses, you will probably need a context only. In this case you can use the Applications context too in many cases. Otherwise you might want to think about restructuring your code.